# How to make Android Multiplayer Games using Facebook friends? (Google Play Game Services uses G+ only)

Tags: android, facebook, multiplayer, google-play-games, nextpeer

At the risk of this question being marked 'research' or 'too broad', I am placing this question here with the research I have done so far (to count as background work), especially since I have been researching this for a while but have not found a good turnkey solution. thank you for your inputs!

I want to make Turn Based Multiplayer Game. I found Google Play Game Services but that only works with Google+ Login: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer

How do I do the same with Facebook login? Can Google Play Game Services be used with Facebook friends?

In my research, the other option I found is nextpeer.com, but not sure if they can do a turn by turn based. I think i have to send player to player messages directly to achieve the turn based player, dont want to do that.

**EDIT**: After I posted the question, i found [Android Games Tutorial with Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/android-tutorial) - trying to understand if turn based game can be done using Facebook SDK.

Can it?

Comment: any updates? were you able to integrate facebook login to google play game services?

Comment: @user2456977 nope. Ended up using Facebook Games API.

Comment: oh interesting! does facebook offer a multiplayer framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am a Nextpeer employee.

Hi,

Nextpeer does not offer a turn based solution at the moment. However, we do have an asynchronous gaming mode in our Facebook matches mode. In this mode players can either play synchronously together or asynchronously. In the second case, a player can play and the recording of his gameplay will be played to his opponents when they choose to play. Does this answer your need?

I'll be glad to discuss further privately, just email us at support@nextpeer.com and ask to talk to Dror.

Comment: Thank you. I am currently researching if I want to use G+ login or facebook login. Nextpeer offers very easy integration with Facebook, but no dedicated mechanism for Turn by turn game. Google game play services does the back end work for me (I am a beginner programmer so want to keep server side work to minimum). Thank you very much for the help, I will reach out when I know exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a solution on similar lines aswell, and I guess we have a solution that can be helpful for others as well. Just looking forward to integrate it. You can find the required documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/android-tutorial)